# Django Invalid Block Tag: 'endfor'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I wrote these for loop, but I got the Error : Django Invalid Block Tag: 'endfor'

```
{ % for post in post_list %}
    <div>
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.created_at }}
    {{ post.photo }}
    {{ post.content }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting that error because there is a space between `{` and `%` where the `for` tag begins.

Change this - `{ %` to look like this - `{%`, *i.e.* remove the space between `{` and `%`:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the space between the first `{` and the `%` sign. 
It should be `{%`